# Do you swirl or twirl a little oil around the frying pan?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage

In my ears, swirl sounds better but I don't know why. I tried looking up the definition for both verbs but I couldn't find anything particularly unique for each, eg something like one of them being used only with inanimate objects. 
Does anyone happen to know some general rules of thumb when to use each of the verbs?

Comment: Twirling is more akin to spinning something around around an axis (you twirl a baton in marching band, you can twirl your hair around your finger), whereas swirl is about making something move in a more fluid, whirly or eddying motion. Liquids always swirl; twirling a liquid conjured up an image of someone magically able to control that liquid and make it move in very unnatural ways.

Comment: Thank you, @JanusBahsJacquet. This answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use **swirl** for causing the liquid to move around the pan. **Twirl** could be used for a ribbon, hair, or even a person spinning. It makes more sense for something moving on an axis.